# PHP: header() and include/include_once/require/require_once

Tags: php, redirect, include, require

I am calling header('Location: http://foo.com/foo/'); in a file after calling include() with files which contain function calls (no output). Whenever I call include() I the PHP header() redirect does not work. This only happens on the server. This happens no matter which PHP file I include. (Local files are uploaded to the server during development.)

---

Well actually I'm getting a blank character just before the DOCTYPE declaration,
which is very bad! I get exactly one blank character whether I include one or two files.

```
    Neil@NEILCOMPUTER /c/wamp/www/workspace/worknet
    $ curl --verbose http://timescapezonecom.ipage.com/worknet/foo.php
    * About to connect() to timescapezonecom.ipage.com port 80 (#0)
    *   Trying 66.96.147.110... connected
    * Connected to timescapezonecom.ipage.com (66.96.147.110) port 80 (#0)
    > GET /worknet/foo.php HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
    > Host: timescapezonecom.ipage.com
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    < Date: Sun, 08 Jul 2012 23:19:12 GMT
    < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    < Content-Length: 206
    < Connection: close
    < Server: Nginx / Varnish
    < X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
    < Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=0310603f03176770c3feb46ea93d9fd3; path=/
    < Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    < Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    < Pragma: no-cache
    < Location: http://www.google.com
    <
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a>.</p>
    </body></html>
    * Closing connection #0
```

On the other hand when I include no files in foo.php I get a zero just before
the doctype, which I also find strange:

```
    Neil@NEILCOMPUTER /c/wamp/www/workspace/worknet 
    $ curl --verbose http://timescapezonecom.ipage.com/worknet/foo.php
    * About to connect() to timescapezonecom.ipage.com port 80 (#0)
    *   Trying 66.96.147.110... connected
    * Connected to timescapezonecom.ipage.com (66.96.147.110) port 80 (#0)
    > GET /worknet/foo.php HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
    > Host: timescapezonecom.ipage.com
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    < Date: Sun, 08 Jul 2012 23:25:28 GMT
    < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    < Content-Length: 206
    < Connection: close
    < Server: Nginx / Varnish
    < X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
    < Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=98c60264dbcdd024d91bae25db848186; path=/
    < Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    < Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    < Pragma: no-cache
    < Location: http://www.google.com
    <
    0<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a>.</p>
    </body></html>
    * Closing connection #0
```

Here is the file foo.php:

```
    <?php
        session_start();

        // I added the require just to make sure nothing is being printed there
        // (an error for example)
    //    require_once('include/connect.php');
    //   require_once('include/util.php');

        header("Location: " . "http://www.google.com");
        exit;
    ?>
```

I'd really like to know where the 0 at the beginning of the file is coming from.

Comment: Are you calling `exit()`/`die()` straight after your header? It's possible some output is being generated and preventing it.

Comment: Yes, after header I am calling exit so that no output will be sent to the browser. This is the way the examples on the PHP site are written. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Nothing, that's the way you should be doing it. I just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: Try using the `curl` command to inspect exactly what your web page is returning.  I would use `curl --verbose http://url`.  Then post here what your results are.  FYI, the PHP manual says that "blank lines" can prevent this redirect from working.  The `curl` output should show exactly what your web page is generating.

Comment: Be sure that you do not have any whitespace after your php closing tag `?>` if you using any, inside you included files.

Comment: Check if the file included has any output, as spaces or any other character.

Comment: Well, on my Windows 7 files created with viPlugin on Aptana I do not think I have any trailing whitespace following the ?>. However, once I upload the file to the ipage.com server who knows what happens, whether my files are transformed to have trailing newline at the end of the file like some text editors do or not. Here is the link: http://timescapezonecom.ipage.com/worknet/foo.php (I am going to reboot into Linux and use curl).

Comment: Some text editors end lines with Windows linebreaks (\r\n) or something similar instead of Linux linebreaks (\n) or the other way around, maybe a file has invisible whitespace at the end or beginning of it, have you checked that out?

Comment: Well, nice for Aptana to have a built-in cygwin terminal so I did not have to reboot into Linux to use curl. I've posted above the output of the command you mentioned...

Comment: So, what's the deal, can anyone explain what's going on. If after uploading to the server you cannot rely on header() being used like this, then PHP is really not that portable is it?

Comment: I think investing into an ipage.com account was a waste. This weired behavior!

Comment: I've uploaded the same files to sourceforge and they work just like on my home Win7 Wamp installation. What the heck did ipage.com do to mess up those files like that???

Comment: I'm surprised that the space or zero makes any difference at all as I would expect for the HTTP 302 status and location to cause a redirect regardless of the HTML in the content.

Comment: Have you grep'd the included files for occurrences of echo or print?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to not use php's closing tag for non-template files.

```
<?php //VERY first line, no whit space
  // code
  // NO ?> *anywhere*
```

Often it's a newline after the ?> which causes your error.

Comment: OK, this is interesting. Where did you find this information? I thought having an open tag but no closing tag would be syntactically incorrect. I'm befuddled.

Comment: It's in the PHP manual, "If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script." http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: It's helpful to think of the closing tag more as the "stop executing" command instead of needing to "close what you open".

Comment: Well, I'm still not happy with the situation. Because I've commented out all the closing tags in my included php files but now, instead of getting the blank character before my <DOCTYPE I am still getting that old 0 ('zero') ASCII character just before my doctype which is not good. The output is exacly as posted above (as though there were no includes) but the '0' characer appears, and I don't want it there (at all actually)!

Comment: So now we're one step closer to fixing the problem. If only the reason for that 'zero' character being there could be figured out. Once again, it only happens on the ipage.com server.